# How can I stop recieving a UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes error message when switching to the emoji keyboard in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have a scroll view with a text field, when the text field is selected I set the scroll view content inset and content offset to make sure the text field is visible. This works fine for the regular keyboard but when I switch to the emoji keyboard I get a UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes error message but my app runs perfectly.

The message says "the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values."

I don't have a collection view in this view controller but I do have one in the view controller that instantiates this one. How can I fix this bug or just hide this error message?

Comment: Also experiencing this now, the issue might be on Apple's end in the emoji keyboard collection view not sure.